# Error: "non-finite finite-difference value" when fitting the Semi-Parametric distribution

Tags: r, distributions, fitting

I am working with Extreme Value Theory.I want to fit a semi-parametric distribution using spdfit in R to get the threshold values in the two tails.
This is the code

```
library("spd")
library("evd")
library("evir")
library("fExtremes")
X<-data$X        #X is the variable to fit
fit_X<-spdfit(X)  
plot(fit_X)
print(fit_X)
```

When I run the first command (spdfit) I get the following error:

> Error in optim(theta, negloglik, hessian = TRUE, ..., tmp = excess) : 
>   non-finite finite-difference value [1]

The code worked with another variable.. I can't find the error..
Thank you for any help you can provide